# OS X dock menu when application is not running

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dock

I'm looking for a way to modify the persistent dock menu of an application when said application is not running, or at least trying to find out if this is even possible? 
I'm using Xcode and Cocoa in Mac OS X version >= 10.5 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a little vague.  What are you trying to "modify" about an app's dock tile, which app, and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to add something to the menu shown when right clicking the dock tile. The application is a launcher app for an X11 application.

Comment: Nope, not possible without hacking that newer versions of OS X don't allow (sandboxing).  Why not just update the app, or rewrite the launcher yourself?

Comment: @CodaFi Not all apps are appropriate for the App Store, and Apple explicitly supports distributing these apps via the Developer ID program. (See [Distributing Outside the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582) in the App Distribution Guide). IMO it is not "hackery" to opt to distribute an app yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is not in the App Store and does not use sandboxing, you can implement a [NSDockTilePlugIn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktileplugin?language=objc)