# How to display an NSOpenPanel from a dock menu

Tags: dock, nsopenpanel

I would like to have a menu item in my application dock menu that displays an `NSOpenPanel` modal dialog, with the following requirements:

- The menu item should work regardless of whether my application is active or inactive.
- The menu item should work regardless of whether my application has open windows or no open windows.
- The `NSOpenPanel` should display on top of all application windows, even windows of other applications, and should accept keyboard input.
- The dock icon for my application should not bounce.
- No windows of my application should be brought forward.

I have yet to find a way to do this. I have tried the following APIs, but all have the potential to violate one or more of the above requirements.

- `NSRunningApplication activateWithOptions:`
- `NSApplication activateIgnoringOtherApps:`
- `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` on the `NSOpenPanel`
- `orderFront:` on the `NSOpenPanel`
- `orderFrontRegardless:` on the `NSOpenPanel`

I did a quick survey of other applications and did not find any with a dock menu item that creates a modal dialog, so I have no proof that it is possible to do what I want.

Supporting the dock menu item when my application is not running is not a requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS X dock menu when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111361/os-x-dock-menu-when-application-is-not-running)

Comment: No. Having a custom dock menu item when the application is not running would be an interesting extension, but that is not my current issue.